# Install4j - windows launcher has previous version of icon

Tags: icons, install4j

I updated the file used for icon of the launcher, but the icon displayed by the launcher is still the previous.

Of course, I've rebuilt the installer (ant in pom) and image pointed in xml is the good one.
Still I have this ghost...

What operation have I missed ? clean a cache ?
I use Install4j v5.1.15

Thx

Comment: On what operating system does this happen and in what context is the launcher icon displayed?

Comment: Hi Ingo, build in on Linux(64) for windows, ghost icon is displayed in a vagrant windows box, in the file explorer.

Comment: What happens if you reboot the computer?

Comment: The computer is a Vagrant VM, it has a phase (durring vagrant up) where it is completed (installs of utils via chocolatey, installs of my projects : DB & API).
There is no hidden image cache file in the folder of my app installer (it has been just rebuilt).

Moreover, in the .exe, when opend with archive manager, the file /.rsrc/ICON/1.ico   is the correct (new) icon.

Comment: Ingo,

Its a kind of magic, so basically, I turned it off and on again
and voilà, the icon is displayed.
Quite illogical because the VM is recreated.

Comment: OK, so this sounds like a problem with the icon cache. Usually, this should never happen.

Comment: I encounter the same problem when dealing with Window 8.1 and instal4j 6